# how to get your app to be supported in different iOS versions?

Tags: ios

I want to start learning Swift right now and the tutorial is for iOS 9 development, so I want to know that if I will follow this tutorial and then want my app to work for iOS 8/7 what will it take? as not all the people upgrage right away I would like to support earlier versions too.

thanks

Comment: Unless you use iOS 9 specific features, your app will work fine in below versions.

Comment: You are only starting out, so focus on the basics first. Different versions of iOS differ in some small ways and most of the times, code for older iOS will run just fine on newer version. Beside that, I recommend that you check out the [iOS version stats](https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store/) from Apple. 91% of devices run iOS 8 or 9. It's up to you on whether you want to target the other 9%.

Comment: @JustAnotherCoder Remember that many users still have the iPhone 4 which was stuck in iOS 7. I read that 12% of users still have iOS 7 (unfortunately for us, developers).

Comment: Don't bother with anything less than iOS9

Comment: Please make an attempt [to search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+support+older+versions+) before posting.

Comment: I don't see the slightest reason this question should be closed.  It's a simple question - but so what? It's perfectly written, etc. The fact that a meaningless close category ("Too Broad" - this question is not in the slightest "broad", it's exceedingly specific) is a hint that the close votes are not appropriate.

Comment: @JoeBlow I still have lots of active users on iOS 7 and 8. There are valid reasons to support versions other than just iOS 9. Each developer needs to make their own assessment of what their app should support.

Comment: Hi maddy.  It's tough.  You make "bugger all" money from 7/8 now.  You get the effect where people with old crap devices just don't waste money on farm games or anything else. For a new developer, it seems an incredibly obscure concern.  :/

Answer (score 1):

Your project name -> General -> Deployment info -> Deployment Target -> Select your target

Be careful, some methods you will use in iOS 9 does not exist in earlier iOS, don't panic if it's the case

Answer (score 0):

Follow the step:-

**1. Select your project from navigator**

[image]

**2. Select Target of your project and go to general tab**

[image]

**3. You can select version as per your lowest version requirement**

[image]

Comment: @Ninja you can upvote and accept answer if you get answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You will not have any problem to run your app in OS X 10.9 and iOS 7 or higher SDK versions. Just select your deployment version in your project settings and that's all.

For further compatibility questions check this [link](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=2).

Answer (score 0):

Open your project settings in Xcode, select your project, and under the "Info" tab, change the deployment target. Your application will be compatible with all OSs newer than the one you choose.

Note that this *can* limit the your code. For example, there is a minimum OS requirement in order to compile certain features, such as Swift or Metal. If the OS you choose is too old for your code, Xcode will give you a warning.

[image: deployment target]